# Why $p|n$ and $r+sp=n^{p-1}\implies p|r$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Why $p|n$ and $r+sp=n^{p-1}\implies p|r$

The implication above appears in the proof of Cauchy's Group Theorem, but I don't see it why, does it require some knowledge of elementary number theory ?

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cauchy's_Group_Theorem

Comment: Note that $p|n$ implies $p|n^{p-1}$ and $p|ps$.

Comment: @sranthrop aha thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p|q$ then there is $k\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $q=pk$, then $n=kp$, if $r+sp=n^{p-1}$:
$$r=n^{p-1}-sp=(kp)^{p-1}-sp=p\cdot(k^{p-1}p^{p-2}-s)\implies p|r$$